# Unable to use custom appender defined in external jar

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I have created a small project which contains an Appender named `MyCustomAppender`. I have created a jar for this project and uploaded it on local repository server.

In another project, I am using the jar created above by putting the dependency in `pom.xml` of this project. This project has a `log4j2.xml` file where all logger configurations reside.
In this `log4j2.xml`, I am trying to use `MyCustomAppender` but it shows following error during server start-up.

```
2021-06-03 12:10:25,473 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 ERROR Error processing element MyCustomAppender ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2021-06-03 12:10:25,802 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 ERROR Unable to locate appender "customAppender" for logger config "CustomLogger"
```

`log4j2.xml` file details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error" monitorInterval="30" >
    <Appenders>
        .
        .
        <MyCustomAppender name="customAppender" >
            <PatternLayout pattern="serial no: %sn |  Date: %d |  level:%level | class name:%logger | method name:%M() |  line number:%L |  Location: %l | message:%m%n" />
        </MyCustomAppender>
        .
        .
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        .
        .
        <Logger name="CustomLogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="customAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        .
        .
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Please direct on how to proceed.

P.S. I am able to access the appender class from inside the other project (in which jar is included).

Comment: The ref should be to `MyCustomAppender`.

Comment: It is to the name of MyCustomerAppender only

Comment: The AppenderRef needs a name property of the appender you created in the appenders section. How is your custom appender annotated? There are multiple docs/blogs detailing this process.

Comment: Actually using same configuration from inside the jar is working fine. but if I include the jar in another project then log4j.xml of that project is not able to use the appender defined in jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the "packages" attribute to the Configuration element?

I am having the same problem loading a custom appender from an external jar file. Curious if you ever figured it out. I'm running on Amazon Corretto on EC2 and wonder if that is related. It works when I test locally.